# Get specified row ranking number

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is the rows looks like:

```
Id  Gold
1   200
2   100
3   300
4   900
5   800
6   1000
```

What I want to achieve is getting the rank number whose `Id` equals to `5`, which is order by `Gold` descending.

So after ordering, the intermediate rows should be(NOT RETURN):

```
Id  Gold
6   1000
4   900
5   800
```

And the SQL should just return `3`, which is the ranking of `Id = 5` row.

What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: You probably want to use RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Gold DESC) and then select the row number of id = 5.

Answer (score 1):

You simply want `top`, I think:

```
select top 3 t.*
from t
order by gold desc;
```

If you want the ranking of `id = 5`:

```
select count(*)
from t
where t.gold >= (select t2.gold from t t2 where t2.id = 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code By using **Dense_rank**():

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
                Dense_rank()
                  OVER(
                    ORDER BY [Gold] DESC) AS rank
         FROM   your_table)
SELECT rank
FROM   cte
WHERE  id = 5
```